# What is the opposite to desc() in R?

Tags: r

I'm new into R and have a question.

arrange(desc(Year)) works perfectly fine. However, instead of having the latest year first I want to have the last year first in my tibble. What is the code for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the default is ascending.. you can use `arrange(Year)`. It may help to read the documentation - see `?dplyr::arrange()`

Comment: @langtang, post as answer?

Answer (score 3):

The default is ascending, so you can simply do:

```
... %>% dplyr::arrange(Year)
```